# GULP: Modify a watched file in place without causing an infinite loop

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-jscs

Im trying to use gulp and jscs to prevent code smell. I also want to use watch so that this happens when ever a change is made. The problem I'm running into is jscs is modify the source file that is being watched. This causes gulp to go into an infinite loop of jscs modifying the file and then watch seeing the change and firing off jscs again and again and again ...

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('/src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(jscs({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(jscs.reporter())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/src'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('/src/**/*.js', ['lint']);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It's generally a bad idea to override source files from a gulp task. Any Editors/IDEs where those files are open might or might not handle that gracefully. It's generally better to write the files into a separate `dist` folder.

That being said here's two possible solutions:

**Solution 1**

You need to stop the `gulp-jscs` plugin from running a second time and writing the files again, thus preventing the infinite loop you're running into. To achieve this all you have to do is add [`gulp-cached`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached#usage) to your `lint` task:

```
var cache = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src('/src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(cache('lint'))
    .pipe(jscs({
        fix: true
    }))
    .pipe(cache('lint'))
    .pipe(jscs.reporter())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/src'));
});
```

The first `cache()` makes sure that only files on disk that have changed since the last invocation of `lint` are passed through. The second `cache()` makes sure that only files that have actually been fixed by `jscs()` are written to disk in the first place.

The downside of this solution is that the `lint` task is still being executed twice. This isn't a big deal since during the second run the files aren't actually being linted. `gulp-cache` prevents that from happening. But if you absolutely want to make sure that `lint` is run only once there's another way.

**Solution 2**

First you should use the [`gulp-watch` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) instead of the built-in [`gulp.watch()`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/5944c1b/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) (that's because it uses the  superior [`chokidar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) library instead of [`gaze`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze)).

Then you can write yourself a simple `pausableWatch()` function and use that in your `watch` task:

```
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

function pausableWatch(watchedFiles, tasks) {
  var watcher = watch(watchedFiles, function() {
    watcher.close();
    gulp.start(tasks, function() {
      pausableWatch(watchedFiles, tasks);
    });
  });
}

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  pausableWatch('/src/**/*.js', ['lint']);
});
```

In the above the `watcher` is stopped before the `lint` task starts. Any  `.js` files written during the `lint` task will therefore not trigger the `watcher`. After the `lint` task has finished, the `watcher` is started up again.

The downside of this solution is that if you save a `.js` file while the `lint` task is being executed that change will not be picked up by the `watcher` (since it has been stopped). You have to save the `.js` file after the `lint` task has finished (when the `watcher` has been started again).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! That fixed the infinite loop. I would also like to figure out how to make it only run the task once.

Comment: @JaredChristensen Since somebody else asked [basically the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978779/i-want-to-automatically-fix-my-css-source-files-but-i-get-an-endless-loop) I had a second look at this and came up with an alternative solution.