# I want to automatically fix my CSS source files, but I get an endless loop

Tags: css, gulp, stylelint

I use gulp-stylefmt and it run every time I save any CSS file:

```js
function stylelint () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe($.stylefmt())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
}
```

Same time *gulp.watch* watches the path `src/**/*.css` and run *stylelint* task again.

Console output:

```bash
[16:32:24] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:25] Finished 'stylelint' after 554 ms
[16:32:25] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:25] Finished 'stylelint' after 60 ms
[16:32:25] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:25] Finished 'stylelint' after 33 ms
[16:32:25] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:25] Finished 'stylelint' after 36 ms
[16:32:26] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:26] Finished 'stylelint' after 34 ms
[16:32:26] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:26] Finished 'stylelint' after 29 ms
[16:32:26] Starting 'stylelint'...
[16:32:26] Finished 'stylelint' after 27 ms
[16:32:26] Starting 'stylelint'…
[16:32:26] Finished 'stylelint' after 32 ms
```

There is a way to correct this behavior and run *stylelint* task only one time?

**UPD**. I added *gulp-cached* and now it runs only twice. Can I improve it to run once?

```js
function stylelint () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe($.cached('stylelint'))
    .pipe($.stylefmt())
    .pipe($.cached('stylelint'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GULP: Modify a watched file in place without causing an infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602702/gulp-modify-a-watched-file-in-place-without-causing-an-infinite-loop)

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Thanks but it helped partly. Better than nothing. Now it runs only twice :)
Should I delete my question?  I'm new here.

Comment: Edited the answer with a solution that should only run the task once.

Comment: For gulp4 no need install _gulp-watch_
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglobs-opts-fn?

Comment: Yeah, gulp4 uses `chokidar` for the built-in `gulp.watch()`, so you don't need the `gulp-watch` plugin. But gulp4's task system is also vastly different, so the answer doesn't work there without modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I repeated the solution 1 by @SvenSchoenung with *since* and *gulp.lastRun*. In my case I did it without *gulp-cached*, but I use *gulp4*

```js
function stylelint () {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css', {since: gulp.lastRun(stylelint)})
 .pipe($.stylefmt())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
}
```

Comment: Awesome for having a gulp 4 solution that's so simple. I was looking for some kind of option like this for ages.